# Aquery vs ButterKnife and Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-loader, aquery, butterknife

What is the difference between using Aquery and Using Butterknife for injection and Picasso for async image loading?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that they have anything to do with one another? This feels like "what is the difference between a person, a rock, and a metaphor?"

Comment: Thanks. Butterknife does injection to lessen the code. And from here:https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Less_Code, one of AQuery's feature is same/similar

Comment: I think he wants to compare Aquery vs ButterKnife. And than use one of those together with Picasso. So it's more like asking about the difference between a person and a rock.

Comment: Yes Rolf, that is correct. thanks

Comment: why don't you guys answer rather than Making fun

Answer (score 1):

Aquery  is better than Picasso because while in offline mode/ No Internet Connectivity ,Picasso tries to fetch record form server whereas Aquery maintains its cache form where it fetched the images .